# SENT Protocol CRC Calaculation

Tags: signals, communication, fpga, sensors

I am generating SENT pulse in my project.
For the SENT protocol  implementation, the data nibbles are 6. So 24 bit data, including a status nibble, CRC nibble and pause pulse.
I need to calculate the CRC for 6 data nibbles. The first value for CRC calculation is 5 as I know.  But when i am decoding the signal with Ozs. I have error in the message because I am sending random value for CRC and for status nibble. So to my questions: how can I calculate the CRC value and status nibbles.
[SENT FRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qctw.png)

```
uint8_t calculatedCRC, i;
const uint8_t CrcLookup[16] = {0, 13, 7, 10, 14, 3, 9, 4, 1, 12, 6, 11, 15, 2, 8, 5};
calculatedCRC = 5; // initialize checksum with seed "0101"

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
calculatedCRC = CrcLookup[calculatedCRC];
calculatedCRC = (calculatedCRC ^ Data[i]) & 0x0F;
}
// One more round with 0 as input
calculatedCRC = CrcLookup[calculatedCRC];
```

I saw this code but I really do not understand how do we get this Lookup table.
[CRC Calculation Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NfgC.png)

i tried to follow the for loop but after the first iteration it is not possible because the calculatedCrc will be in 11^11. please i need your help!

```
1)  i=0 >>> calculatedCRC== 11
2)  i=1 >>> calculatedCRC== 
3)  i=2 >>> calculatedCRC
4)  i=3 >>> calculatedCRC
5)  i=4 >>> calculatedCRC
6)  i=5 >>> calculatedCRC
```

Comment: The very first thing you need is the CRC polynomial. Also wiki has complete code examples and GIF animation of how gates are used to calculate a CRC. Last but not least: show us you code plus test-bench. Without that nothing goes.

Comment: i am sorry i could not post the code so i post that with screenshot. which code do you mean ? the code for the pulse generation ? it is too complicated to post it here

Comment: Please do not add a screenshot. Edit your question, paste the code and format it correctly, using proper indenting and preceded by four spaces

Comment: and please where can i find examples ?